# Ubuntu как запустить беж папки usr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Имеется старый ноут, на котором я в отчаяние удалил папку /usr дабы почистить все пакеты и установить их потом по новой, но после этого система отказыается запускатся и выбивает kernal panic.
Есть способ хотя бы скопировать файлы оттуда?

Comment: Проще всего загрузиться через `live-cd`, примонтировать нужные разделы и скопировать оттуда необходимое. А ОС установить заново.

Comment: Родную систему — никак.